# Excel or VBA Trim Words to certain character limit

Tags: excel, vba

I Have some products in a list which I need to trim the words down to 6 characters each also the character limit cant be longer 20 (so it would have to trim the sentence again down to 20 characters)

example

Southern Comfort = Southe Comfor (this is the result I am needing)

Courvoisier = Courvo

I would prefer to be able to do this using an excel formula if not then VB

Many Thanks

Comment: Hi Mitch if its vba I would an example of the code if possible, as I'm still very new with it, thankyou

Comment: Use VBA and specify the word delimiter and processing logic of special characters like "!", "?", etc (e.g. "It's Mine!!!" - what it should return?). Rgds,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it can really be done with formula. You need a `For/Each` structure to trim *each word* and then recombine the sentence and trim that result.  VBA would be the way to go.

Use the `Split` function and a suitable delimiter (most likely a space character) to convert the sentence to an array of words, and then iterate the words to create a new string.

**Modified from comments requesting a UDF function**

call from the worksheet like `=foo(A1)`, etc.

```
Function foo(r as Range)
Dim sentence As Variant
Dim w As Integer
Dim ret as String 

    ' assign this cell's value to an array called "sentence"
    sentence = Split(r.Value, " ")

    ' iterate each word in the sentence
    For w = LBound(sentence) To UBound(sentence)
        ' trim to 6 characters:
        sentence(w) = Left(sentence(w), 6)
    Next

    ' Join the array back to a string/sentence
    ret = Join(sentence, " ")

    'Make sure the sentence is max 20 chars:
    ret = Left(ret, 20)


    'return the value to your function expression:
    foo = ret
End Function
```

Comment: david thanks for the quick reply can this be done as a function which I can call upon in formula as the cell numbers are all different?

Comment: It can be... modified slightly, revised answer above.

Comment: thanks David this works exactly as I need